# Can we call nested function like this ?(condition calling)

Tags: python, function, nested

```
def hello(name ="jose"):
    print("hello" ,name)
    #global greet
    def greet():
        print("Welcome")
```

> hello(greet())

I want call inside function only when I need it . I don't want to call it everytime by giving it global keyword or returning own function .
Is there any other way ?

Comment: The name of the function, `greet`, is local to `hello`, so you can't access it from outside. Do you have a real reason to use a nested function?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille not real reason but i was wondering if I have call inside function particularly for some input without exposing the inside function body then how would I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add condition to do that. For example

```py
def hello(name ="jose", is_call_greet=False):
     print("hello" ,name)
     #global greet
     def greet():
          print("Welcome")

     if is_call_greet:
         greet()
```

Or return the function

```py
def hello(name ="jose"):
     print("hello" ,name)
     #global greet
     def greet():
          print("Welcome")

     return greet;    

hello()() # call greet
hello() # not call greet
```

Comment: wouldn't your second code will always print greet?

Comment: It would not print "Welcome" by greet when only call hello(), you could try it.
The console will show output is greet. If you don't want to show the output, you can put greet = hello().